# Split string in Entity framework in Object Collection i.e in New {}

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hi I have one doubt in entity framework query.I am returning this result from one of the my action in controller.

```
return q.select(t=> new 
{
  date1,
  date2,
  Name,
  Status
});
```

date1,date2 are the string field in database which return comma separated dates.
I want to take only first date from date1.But unable to get it.
Can some one please help me to get the first date.
I tried couple of thing like

```
date1 = date1.split(',')[0]; 
date1 = date1.split(',').take(0).firstOrDefault();
```

but facing this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[]
>   Split(Char[])'  method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Comment: You need to use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` to bring your query in memory before using C# methods like `Split`. If the data is huge better return desired data from DB itself.

Comment: As an aside, storing dates like that means you have a major problem with your database schema. Each column should be discrete and of an appropriate data type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error is pretty self-descriptive - EF cannot create SQL code which will do string splitting. You can only download data into memory and then do splitting:

```
 q.Select(t=> new { // translated into SQL
     t.date1, 
     t.date2, 
     t.Name, 
     t.Status
   })
  .AsEnumerable() // moves further execution into memory
  .Select(x => new {
      data1 = x.data1.Split(',')[0], // now you can use any c# code here
      x.data2,
      x.Name,
      x.Status
  });
```

First `Select` statement is translated into SQL query:

```
SELECT date1, date2, Name, Status FROM table
```

And it makes sense to keep it if your table has lot of fields to avoid transferring all those fields over network.

Next you use `AsEnumerable()` to process database query results in memory.

And second `Select` statement is used to project query results into something you need with all power of C# code without need to be translated into SQL.

Comment: @TimSchmelter true :)